# Dango: list index out of range after, after 10 loops even though there is more left in the list

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose to take entry from a form entry for a list of cards. Then split each entry into a list after a new line.

No matter what is in the form text area box, it reaches out of range after 9 entries.

Have tried multiple different card examples, no matter what is there will always crash after 9 entries.

```
def new_deck(request):
    form = mtgForm()
    current_user = request.user
    add_deck = Decks(deck_name=request.POST['Deck_Name'], user_id=current_user.id)
    add_deck.save()
    decks_id = add_deck.deck_id
    if request.method == "POST":
        current_user = request.user
        cards_from = request.POST['cards']
        cards_from_form = cards_from.split("\r\n")
        cards_from_form[:] = [x for x in cards_from_form if x]
        for i, dataa in enumerate(cards_from_form):
            amount_of_cards = ''.join(x for x in dataa if x.isdigit())   
            pattern = r'[0-9]'
            ccards_name = re.sub(pattern, '', dataa).lstrip()
            ccards = Card.where(name=f'"{ccards_name}"').all()
            #ccard_id = ccards[0:1].number
            ccard_name = ccards[0].name
            ccard_type = ccards[0].type
            ccard_cost = ccards[0].mana_cost
            ccard_toughness = ccards[0].toughness
            ccard_power = ccards[0].power
            ccard_rarity = ccards[0].rarity
            ccard_set = ccards[0].set
            ccard_color_idenity = ccards[0].color_identity
            add_cards = cards(card_name=ccard_name, card_type=ccard_type, card_cost=ccard_cost, card_toughness=ccard_toughness,card_power=ccard_power,card_rarity=ccard_rarity,card_set=ccard_set,card_color_idenity=ccard_color_idenity,deck_id=decks_id)
            add_cards.save()
        return HttpResponse("Cards added to deck")
    else:
        return render(request, "form.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
cards_from = request.POST['cards']
cards_from_form = cards_from.split("\r\n")
cards_from_form[] = [x for x in cards_from_form if x]
```

Try:

```
cards_from_form = request.POST.getlist('cards')
```

request.POST is an instance of django.http.request.QueryDict

And a querydict is not a dict. If you try in a shell :

```
dict = QueryDict.fromkeys(["a", "a", "b"], value="val") #create a new querydict
print(dict['a'])
```

Output will be 'val', not list ["val","val"].

To get the list you have a quarydict method:

QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None):

Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and default is None. It’s guaranteed to return a list unless the default value provided isn’t a list.